# How do different browsers handle mixed/insecure content?

Tags: google-chrome, security, http, browser, https

Not entirely sure whether SO is the place for this but I'm wanting to know what the default behaviour is for different browsers. It appears that Chrome will block insecure scripts from running but when it comes to insecure images it will load them and just warn that there was/is mixed content.

I want to know what the default behaviours are for different browsers (Without using a CSP header).

Answer (score 0):

Best resource I can find is this one:

https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2014/03/19/https-mixed-content-still-the-easiest-way-to-break-ssl

Though it's nearly two years old now. They do list a test you can do yourself by visiting this URL with several browsers:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html

At the bottom it lists the detail. Annoyingly their, otherwise excellent, [user agents report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html) doesn't include this section so you do have to run this yourself with several browsers.